# General approach to determining if a subset is a subgroup if it has finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am a little confused as how to approach problems that ask whether a subset is a subgroup given that it has the property of being of finite order e.g. in the case for $GL(N,\mathbb{R}$). What property of a subset does being finite violate exactly?

EDIT: Sorry for the ambiguity, I mean take for example a subset $H$ of the group $G=GL(N,\mathbb{R}$). If $H$ is the set of elements of $G$ of finite order, why exactly is $H$ not a subgroup?

Comment: Hard to understand the question, harder when you go from "subgroup" to "subspace" without signalling. The group you name does have finite subgroups.

Comment: None. I've read this multiple times, and don't understand what exactly you are asking. Consider clarifying maybe? Are you talking about subgroups or subspaces? How exactly does $Gl_n \left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ relate to what you say before you mention it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hope that clarifies my question

Comment: @gnometorule Hope that clarifies my question a bit

Comment: @bobdylan, I love your music but your edit is even more confusing. Do you mean to say why is $H$ not a subgroup?

Comment: @JacobSchlather Thank you, yes this is exactly what i mean

Comment: I wonder whether what you are thinking of os that the set of *all* elements of your $g$ of finite order is not a subgroup of $g$. The thing there is that you can multiply two elements of finite order and get an element that isn't of finite order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are finite subgroup of $GL(N, \mathbb{R})$.

A set of elements of finite order, $H \subset GL(N, \mathbb{R})$, may or may not be a *subgroup*.

$H$ is a subgroup if it contains the identity element of $GL(N, \mathbb{R}) = I_N$, and if it is closed under matrix multiplication (for $A, B \in H$ it is also true that $AB$ and $BA \in H$), and if for every element $h\in H, \; h^{-1} \in H$.

If all these properties are satisfied, then $H$, finite or otherwise, is a *subgroup* of $GL(N, \mathbb{R})$.  If any of these properties fail to hold, then $H$ is strictly a *subset* of $GL(N, \mathbb{R})$.

---

***Challenge*** One can also prove a *stronger statement*:

> If $H$ is a *non-empty finite subset* of a group $G$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ *if and only if* it is *closed under the binary operation* of $G$.

That is, if $H$ is a non-empty finite subset of group $G$, then it suffices to prove that it is closed under the group operation of $G$. To show this, one shows that closure of non-empty finite $H$ ensures that the identity of $G$ is necessarily in $H$, and for every element $h\in H$, $h^{-1} \in H.$

Comment: I didn't see such this before. It needs more reflects. +

Comment: @amWhy's answer is a form of the subgroup criterion. This is a common result that can be used to show that a subset of a group is a subgroup. See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sufficiency_of_subgroup_criterion for more details.

Comment: @bobdylan A finite subset of a group is a subgroup iff it closed under multiplication, so there is no need to check all three conditions.

Comment: Correction @YACP - A NONEMPTY finite subset of a group is a subgroup of the group iff it is closed under the GROUP'S OPERATION.  I.e. for any group G, $\varnothing \subset G$, but $\varnothing \nleq G$, and for $H \subseteq G$, $H$ finite, $H\neq \varnothing$, the closure of $H$ must be with respect to the group operation of $G$, which may or may not be multiplication.

Comment: @DavidWard Nice link!

Comment: A nitpick can't be a correction, but is good that you followed what I said and changed your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case, consider the two elements of $\text{GL}(2, \mathbf{R})$
\begin{equation}
a = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
b = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Verify that $a^2 = b^2 = 1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Now consider
\begin{equation}
c = a b = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
and note that 
\begin{equation}
c^n = \begin{bmatrix}1 & n\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
so that $c$ has infinite order.